# Wordpress Specific page redirect from Old Domain

Tags: wordpress, iis, dns, web-config, redirect

I have look for an answer on this but I have not found one. I had a site http://oldsite.com this site was plain ol' HTML and the domain is host with godaddy. I've created a new site in Wordpress and the domain is http://newsite.com the new site is been host in a IIS server.

My problem, I'm trying to redirect http://oldsite.com/page1.html to http://newsite.com/page1

How can I achieve this? I have change the "A" record in godaddy to point to this new server IP and install a 301 redirection plugin in wordpress but when I go to http://oldsite.com/page1.html it redirects to the new site 404 page.

Should I do this with web.config? I'm open to suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: in this case you need to add 301 in the oldsite.com, so that it wont redirect to 404 page, if you add 301 redirects in newdomain absolutely it will throw 404

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by following below -

1. On the oldsite.com server, add a 301 redirect to corrosponding newsite page. 301 redirect can be done at the page level, or it can be set at the webserver level.
2. If you now don't have access to the oldsite.com now, then in your newsite.com you need to add rules for redirecting each url type to the corrosponding url types. This can be achieved using .htaccess rules or webconfig rules.

If the changes in the urls is just the domain names and removal of .php than simply putting access rules can fix this issue, otherwise you will have to write a mapping rule for each type.

Preferred way is point no.1 as it won't hurt the seo and other things, it will simply redirect everything to newwebsite.com wherever you want.

Comment: The oldsite.com not longer has hosting. Only the domain register in the account. I change the DNS "A" record to point to the new server and I added rules in the webconfig file such as

`<rule name="My Test Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="oldsite.com/page-1.html" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="newsite.com/page/new-page" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>`